# creating thread inside child process

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int value=0;
void *runner(void *param);
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int pid;
pthread_t tid;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pid=fork();
if(pid==0){
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_create(&tid,&attr,runner,NULL);
pthread_join(tid,NULL);
printf("CHILD VALUE=%d",value);
}
else if(pid>0){
wait(NULL);
printf("PARENT VALUE=%d",value);
}
}


void *runner(void *param){
value=5;
pthread_exit(0);
}
```

what is the value of child and parent??
will the child and the thread created by it share the data? so output will be 5 and 0?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: 5 for the child, 0 for the parent. fork() creates a new process, and, therefore, gives you space isolation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this kind of question can be easily figured out by simply running the code involved. I'm going to close both of your questions, please don't post it a third time.

Answer (score 1):

> will the child and the thread created by it share the data?

No. The child process can be thought of as getting **a copy** if the parent's memory. Thus any changes made by the child are not visible to the parent.

> so output will be 5 and 0?

Yes: child prints 5, parent prints 0 (not necessarily in this order).

Answer (score 1):

What happens is this:

- the child process is created by duplicating the memory space of the parent. It will see the same data as the parent, but it's only a copy, so they cannot interfere with eachother. Any subsequent changes done by the child process (or any of its threads!) will only be visible to itself.
- the thread spawned by the child shares the memory space with the main thread of the child process and, again, sees a copy of the values in the parent process.

Hence, since the value assigned in the thread spawned by the child will only be visible inside the child process, but not inside the parent process, the results are 5 and 0.